# How does Python handle an OpenCV-triggered loop without interfering with a GPIO setup?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

So I put together all my little programming knowledge and started writing a python code that works with opencv and should perform an action on my old nintendo ds.

What I wanted to do is, first get a little bit more knowledge on Raspberry Pi projects and second build a device that searches for Pokémon.

Might sound silly but a little background:
"Shiny Pokémon" are the same as normal ones but with a different color. Nothing else to it but you can hunt for one and some people have the patience to do it. I don't, but still wanna do my own hunt.
The chance of one appearing is 1/8192 in the games I'm trying to cover so they are pretty rare.
There are a few videos out there trying and succeeding at this but no guide on how to pull it off automatically. There are also a few videos on opencv that helped me pull this off.

Luckily you can start the game, encounter the Pokémon and see it's color by just pressing the A button. If it isn't the color you want, the program should perform a "soft reset" basically restaring the game with a certain button press combination (Start, Select, L and R) and continuing the cycle of checking. It should stop and wait for human input if the color isn't the one of a normal Monster, meaning it is shiny.

Buttons are pressed by giving them a 3.3V signal with a hard soldered wire so an old ds unit had to suffer.

I noticed that the other button don't interfere with the game itself should you not press all of them at the same time.
So I made sure that power is delivered to Start and Select and R is taped down. L is pressed with a servo motor triggering the reset.
For noticing colors i used OpenCV.

Now onto my code that might be a mess:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #Start Camera
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
servo1 = GPIO.PWM(13, 50)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Press A again and again
    GPIO.output(11, 1)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(11, 0)

    # Define my Pokemon
    low_green = np.array([31, 31, 72])
    high_green = np.array([65, 253, 168])
    green_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_green, high_green)

    #Define Giratina (the one I'm hunting for)
    low_red = np.array([166, 72, 127])
    high_red = np.array([178, 180, 245])
    red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_red, high_red)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Cherry", green_mask)
    cv2.imshow("Giratina", red_mask)
    #Show masks and camera

    if cv2.countNonZero(green_mask) > 20000 and cv2.countNonZero(green_mask) < 30000 and cv2.countNonZero(red_mask) > 1500 and cv2.countNonZero(red_mask) < 5000 :
        #If my mon is present and Giratina is normal
        # Just this one servo is enough to press the button to softreset
        servo1.start(0)
        servo1.ChangeDutyCycle(8.9)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        servo1.ChangeDutyCycle(2)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        servo1.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
        servo1.stop()
        print("No Shiny! Soft Resetting")

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
servo1.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
print("End of the hunt!")
```

The numbers of the color recognition don't matter cause I manually add them once I placed the device in a box for consistent lighting.

What works?

The A button is being pressed according to plan no problem here.
The if-statement also seems to trigger and the servo is started.

What's the problem then?

The servo seems to trigger but only once.
It has the same lighting and conditions but after performing the reset once it just won't trigger again. Might be a real bold mistake, but I can't put my finger on it alone.
Additionally sometimes the Servo pressing the button just seem to restart my Pi, but not always.
I thought that it might have something to do with the button "A" and the servo being controlled at the same time and it being too much for the Pi but shouldn't that be impossible with the if-statement?
The other buttons (Start, Select not the taped one) are powered by a completely different power source so they hopefully don't interfere with the button "A" and the servo.

Thanks in advance, I hope I have described my problem somewhat competent. Have a nice one.

Comment: It's nice to hear about your project but the problem you have has nothing to do with OpenCV. Please rewrite the question to focus on programming the hardware. Also, consider writing a minimal and complete example that reproduces the problem you are facing. These things make it much easier for you get help from others.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer.
I included a more complete introduction and opencv cause I couldn't really pinpoint the source of any problem myself.
If it's not about opencv that's at least good news to hear.
I admit I got kinda intimidated by the very specific way this platform wants you to ask questions that I certainly have written more than I need to.
If it's more hardware related, how would you formulate my problem?

Comment: First, start with writing a complete minimal example that reproduces the issue. Here's how to do it: write a new program that controls the hardware through key presses. Make sure to cover all the operations that you need it to do. My guess is that you'll encounter the problem during this experiment. When that happens, come back, rewrite the question and someone will be able to help you.